# How to stop PlaySync in SoundPlayer on button click

Tags: vb.net, winforms, loops, synchronization

Example :

- input number of sound from 5 to 92
- then audio will play continously from audio5 to audio92
- i want to stop in the middle

Here my code :

```
Sub playsound()
    Dim from1 As Integer
    If Not Integer.TryParse(TextBox1.Text, from1) Then
        Return
    End If

    Dim to1 As Integer
    If Not Integer.TryParse(TextBox2.Text, to1) Then
        Return
    End If

    For i As Integer = from1 To to1
        Dim sound As String = "D:\Audio\audio" & i.ToString & ".wav"
        Dim media As New Media.SoundPlayer(sound)
        media.PlaySync()
    Next
```

BtnPlay Click :

```
    If TextBox1.Text < 3 Then
        MessageBox.Show("Audio strat from audio3")

    ElseIf TextBox1.Text = "" Or TextBox2.Text = "" Then
        MessageBox.Show("Can't empty")

    ElseIf TextBox1.Text > 100 Or TextBox2.Text > 100 Then
        MessageBox.Show("Audio finish at audio100")

    ElseIf TextBox1.Text > TextBox2.Text Then
        MessageBox.Show("Audio can't play backwards")
    Else
        Call playsound()
    End If
```

Comment: I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After experimenting ***a lot*** with the WinAPI function [**`PlaySound()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd743680(v=vs.85).aspx) (which the [**`SoundPlayer` class**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.media.soundplayer(v=vs.110).aspx) is using) I have found that it is simply not possible to stop synchronous sounds. What you are trying to do is not possible using the `SoundPlayer` class, I'm afraid.

You should look into other libraries that you can use as a replacement for the `SoundPlayer` class. You could for instance use [**Windows Media Player**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd564582(v=vs.85).aspx), which comes pre-installed on most Windows systems.

Comment: then it can't play continuously and loop will be useless?

Comment: @HazuKeil : Sorry, I misread your question. I have edited the answer.

Comment: I can't found TaskCreationOptions.DenyChildAttach, the option is AttachedToParent, LongRunning, None, PreferFairness. Now the stop button can clicked but the sound is not stopped.

Comment: @HazuKeil : Use `TaskCreationOptions.None` then. Please see the edit on my answer.

Comment: I have already follow your instruction but it's still can't stopped sound

Comment: @HazuKeil : No, I edited it again. See [the revisions](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/43536369/revisions). -- Just copy-paste the code again and it should work.

Comment: I have checked it 5 times but its still cant stopping. Here the differents : Dim media As media.SoundPlayer, End If statement placed after exit for, i have two end sub because there is two sub (sub playsound and sub())

Comment: @HazuKeil : Hmm... I'm on my way home so I'll check it out when I get there.